# Upload photo to Facebook page in a specific album

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, upload, photo

I am busy with uploading a photo to Facebook. The requirement is that we need to upload the photo on a specific album on a page. This is the link to the page : https://business.facebook.com/manegedagen/.

I can successfully upload a photo to the timeline but my requirement is to upload the photo in an album. So below i first start with getting all albums from a specific page.

```
    public void getAlbum() {
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/2091172661108128/albums",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    pageAlbums = new Gson().fromJson(response.getRawResponse(), FacebookResponseAlbum.class);

                    postImageOnWall(bitmap);
                    Log.e("", "");
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

In this case this 2091172661108128 is the id of the page for which i am getting a list of albums. 
So later i am trying to post a picture on a specific album

```
 public void postImageOnWall(Bitmap pBitmap) {
    Album dttAlbum = getDttAlbum(pageAlbums);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    String a = String.valueOf( dttAlbum.getId() ).concat("/photos");
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("object_attachment", byteArray);// object attachment must be either byteArray or bitmap image
    bundle.putString("message", "hey fibs it works");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            String.valueOf( dttAlbum.getId() ).concat("/photos") ,
            bundle,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    Log.e("", "");
                }

            }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

The problem is that i am getting : {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Permissions error}} as response.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the value of the string you are creating there …?

Comment: Since your getAlbum method returns a collection of albums, I rather doubt that calling dttAlbum.getId() makes any actual sense ...

Comment: PageAlbums class is wrapper class which contains an array of albums. When i get all albums for a specific page i use that model with Gson to create a POJO object. The date is correct since i checked it with a debugger. But the strange thing is i am getting "Permission error"

Comment: What permissions does your app have from the user? // You are not dealing with a normal page here, but a business page - things might be different for those.

Comment: Also, what API version are you using? I just see that according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/album/photos, the photos edge of the album object was removed (also that might be a documentation error, not sure.)

Comment: @CBroe , Thank you for you reply, when a user log-in i just setReadPermissions("email") on the loginButton. Apart from that in my grade i am using 
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'.

Comment: Trying to publish anything with just _read_ permissions does not make much sense.

Comment: i didnt really get your-idea, can you perhaps elaborate what should i do ?
regards

Comment: Well you must have more permissions than just `email`, if you want to publish anything ...